# World Map that calls Popup charts on clickable data points

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

## World Map with clickable location points

#### Below is the code, note I have a pop-up window as a placeholder, but I want a graph instead.

> Right now, I have a working world map that depicts location points via small red dots. These dots are clickable. Right now, as a placeholder, I have a pop up window open when the dots are clicked. But I want a graph to show up when clicked instead. I attempted to use google charts but since my map was not a google chart, I could not use its action listener function. I am new to data visualizations and am still trying to learn. Does anyone know of a way to do this with google charts or maybe another JavaScript library? I am open to learning :) I was thinking that I should make another JSP page, which handles the creation of the chart, then call that page when the point on the map is clicked. But this all theory, and I am not sure how to implement this. Is there any way that this could be done? Or maybe any other ideas. I have many data viz problems that I am working on, so I know this information will be helpful and applicable to many other projects, that are not just my own.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
          .background {
          fill: none;
          pointer-events: all;
          }      

          path {
              stroke: white;
              stroke-width: 0.25px;
              fill: grey;
          }

          body {
              text-align: center;
          }

          div.DoD {
              position: absolute;
              text-align: center;
              width: 60px;
              padding: 8px;
              font: 10px sans-serif;
              background: #ddd;
              border: solid 1px #aaa;
              pointer-events: none;
          }

          .city {
              cursor: pointer;
          }

          .box {
              border: solid 1px #ccc;
          }

          .map {
              margin-bottom:20px;
          }

          #slider-step {
              width:300px;
              margin: 0 auto;
             margin-bottom: 5px;
         }

     </style>
     <title>HW7</title>
 </head>
 <body>

    <!-- Load scripts in the body -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/jquery.nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <link href="assets/jquery.nouislider.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <h1> United States Summer Olympic Medals </h1>
    <div class="map"></div>
    <div id="slider-step"></div>
    <span id="slider-value">2012</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var width = 960;
            height = 480;
            centered = null;
            minDate = 2012;

  // Create a mercator projection since 2D
       var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
           .center([0, 5])
           .scale(150);

  // Create SVG object
      var svg = d3.select(".map").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .attr("class", "box")

      svg.append("rect")
         .attr("class", "background")
         .attr("width", width)
         .attr("height", height)
         .on("click", clicked);

  // Instantiate the path using projection()
      var path = d3.geo.path()
          .projection(projection);

  // Create svg group
      var g = svg.append("g");

      render();

      function render() {
         g.selectAll("circle").remove();
    // Draw the map
        d3.json("json/world_map.json", function(error, topology) {

      // Location functionality on the world_map
        d3.csv("data/us_medals.csv", function(error, data) {
              data = data.filter(function(row) {
                  return row['Games'] < minDate + 1;
        })

          g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                          return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0];
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                          return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1];
            })
            .attr("r", 4)
            .attr("d", data)
            .attr("class", "city")
            .style("fill", "red")
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mousemove", mousemove)
            .on("mouseout", mouseout)
            .on("click", clicked);
      });

      // Countries
      g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.countries).features)
      .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
    });
  }

  // iniital DoD with help from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1087001
  var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "DoD")
      .style("opacity", 0);

  function mouseover() {
    div
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }

  function mousemove(d) {
    div
      .text(d.City)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
  }

  function mouseout() {
      div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
  }

  // Zoom code from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590
  function clicked(d) {

    window.open("", "", "HELLO", "width=200, height=100");
    var x, y, k;

    mouseout();

    if (d && centered !== d) {
      var x = projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0];
          y = projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1];
          k = 4;
      centered = d;
    } else {
      x = width / 2;
      y = height / 2;
      k = 1;
      centered = null;
    }

    g.selectAll("path")
        .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d === centered; });

    g.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
        .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
  }

  $('#slider-step').noUiSlider({
    start: [ 2012 ],
    connect: "lower",
    step: 4,
    range: {
      'min': [  1896 ],
      'max': [ 2012 ]
    }
  });

  $('#slider-step').on("slide", setRange);

  function setRange() {
    var value = $("#slider-step").val();
    $("#slider-value").text(Math.floor(value));
    minDate = value;
    render();
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you want a graph to replace the map or do you want it in a pop up window or modal?